# Unable to locate File in Jenkins Job using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, filenotfoundexception, jenkins-job-dsl

In my automation script using Selenium with Java, I am trying to upload a document from project path, using below syntax:

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "./src/test/resources/ID.png";
```

And the script runs absolutely fine when I ran via maven command locally.

But when the same script is executed via Jenkins Job, it throws an error stating:

> java.lang.Exception: Unable to upload the Document: invalid argument: File not found :
> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Batch./src/test/resources/ID_&_Passport.png

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\JDGAuto_Batch_IC./src/test/resources/ID_&_Passport.png` - this path is sensitive, try changing to D or some other location in C, like downloads folder etc

Comment: While running from Jenkins, project is saved automatically at this location  and from there it tried to get the file to upload.
I don't know, if we have option to change location where our project would be saved.

Comment: I bet it will work with `String filePath = "src/test/resources/ID.png";`